# Execute a mysql_query at random. 

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to execute a random query ... at random 1-15 attacks
The below is a php query for a game.
it gets executed when a player hits the attack button. i simplified the query for simplicity's sake.

In other words what im trying to do is///

**randomly every 10 attacks to this specific ship_id run the query to insert**

**what i have so far is wrong** in terms of the random generator but hopefully will make my point.

-------------------------The random hit would be below this line

```
        **function RandNumber($e){


  for($i=0;$i<$e;$i++){
  $rand =  $rand .  rand(0, 9);  
  }
  return $rand;

  }

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$game}_ships (ship_name,login_name,shipclass,class_name,class_name_abbr,fighters,max_fighters,max_shields,cargo_bays,mine_rate_metal,mine_rate_fuel,config,size,upgrades,move_turn_cost,point_value,location,login_id
    ) values(
    'FC1','$user[login_name]','427','fc','  Sc','5967','5967','10442','2003','5','45','bs:dt:ot','6','99','19','45',1,'$user[login_id]')");
  echo "<div class='success'>427 </div>";**
```

anyone can point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I don't see any code that has click tracking. Please post that code before we can help you. Also normally you insert into tables, not databases.

Comment: its not tracked by clicks. my mistake. i updated the question.

Comment: you say random but you say once every 15 clicks.  if you want specific number like every 15 clicks, then track the clicks by storing it in database (hits=hits+1)  then check if hits%15=0    but if you totally random, then you can use rand(0,15) but no need for for and return. also the query is wrong

Comment: the query i right, i truncated it as its over 1500 lines long. the part that does not work is the random insert im trying to implement. i would rather use random instead of xccreating another column.

Comment: track the hits , since this is a game, you want to know how many hits it received. to be constant and control how many hits.  see my previous comment.  every hit record it. then check if hit%10 (if divided by 10 left is 0)   if you then want to make it random not exact 10, then you could get a number using $target=rand(9,15); and then if ($hit%$target)

Comment: problem there is that these are bot ships designed to die in one or two attacks. thats why a column wouldn't do any good. im trying to execute the query at random from 1-15. thats what im having trouble accomplishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the hits if you want an exact number like every 10 hits, or every 9-15 hits.
you track it by running inserting a query every hit

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO YOURTABLE SET hits=hits+1 LIMIT 1");
```

then you fetch that same hits from the db and check whether it is 10

```
if ($hits%10==0){INSERT YOUR QUERY IN QUESTION}
```

but if you want just by random from 1-15 regardless of hits count then:

```
  $rand =  rand(1, 15);  //but I would go with 1,5  this will be totally random, I think tracking hits is better 


  if ($rand==1){
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$game}_ships (ship_name,login_name,shipclass,class_name,class_name_abbr,fighters,max_fighters,max_shields,cargo_bays,mine_rate_metal,mine_rate_fuel,config,size,upgrades,move_turn_cost,point_value,location,login_id
     ) values(
      'FC1','$user[login_name]','427','fc','  Sc','5967','5967','10442','2003','5','45','bs:dt:ot','6','99','19','45',1,'$user[login_id]')");
  echo "<div class='success'>427 </div>";
  }
```

Comment: i will take your suggestion under heavy consideration. i like it, however it doesn't suit the purpose of this function. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Something that some big sites do is every 100 or so page loads, it'll update the page views by 100.

This is done by getting a random number from 1-100 (in your case 1-15) and if it happens to be `1` (for example), then it'll add 100 values into the database.

So for your case, in the script select  a random number from 1-15. if the result is `1`, run the query.

Comment: Interesting technique, but could cause some large discrepancies, couldn't it?

Comment: im going for small numbers here.

Comment: ofcourse it's not going to be absolutely perfect on numbers. but if you want to make it perfect on numbers you're going to have to run a db query (or similar) to keep a count of every single page load.